# How to prove $e<e\zeta(e+1)<e+1$ ? ($\zeta(x)$ is Riemann zeta function)

Tags: sequences-and-series

If there is the following function in x>1,
$$\zeta(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n^x}}$$
how to prove "$e<e\zeta(e+1)<e+1$" ?

I found a value on the Internet when x is 3 or 4 and I put it in the above equation, and I've actually verified this expression is true.
$$e<e\zeta(4)\cong2.942<e\zeta(e+1)<e\zeta(3)\cong3.267<e+1$$
**However, the problem didn't mention the "Riemann Zeta Function" and it is in the high school curriculum**, so it seems to have to be solved not to use the nature of the zeta function, but I can't think of a way.
How can I solve it?

Comment: The left inequality is pretty simple at least, just bound the terms other than $n = 1$ from below by $0$.

Comment: I don't know what that means, but I think I know how to solve the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bruno B stated, the left inequality is simple since $\zeta(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{2^x} + \sum_{n = 3}^{\infty} > 1$. For the right, we establish an upper bound on $\zeta(s)$ by interpreting it as an approximation to the integral $\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^s}$. More specifically,

$$
\zeta(s) - 1 = 2^{-s} + 3^{-s} + \cdots < \int_1^{\infty} x^{-s} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{s - 1}
$$

(Draw a graph!) So $e\zeta(e + 1) < e\left(1 + \frac{1}{e}\right) = e + 1$.

What a nice problem :)

Comment: Aha!!!!! "Hold on..." and keep looking at your solution, and finally understand it! This wasn't such a difficult question!